# delete all user-defined global variables in an imported python module

Tags: python, variables, module

I have a Python script that imports a series of other Python scripts by name through `__import__`, then calls the script's `main` function.  After each import is complete, I want to reclaim any memory allocated by the script, as some of them create large in-memory structures as globals (I don't have control over the globals part.)

My intended approach is to simply loop through `vars()` and delete each non-private variable, thusly:

```
for m in ['imp1', 'imp2', 'imp3']:

    this_mod = __import__(m)
    this_mod.main()

    # delete the module's globals
    mvars = [ i for i in vars(this_mod) if not i.startswith('__') ]
    for var in mvars:
        delattr(this_mod, var)
```

Is this a reasonable approach and/or are there any gotchas I should be aware of?

Comment: `this_mod` should be garbage collectible after each iteration.

Comment: @Hyperboreus -- Unlikely.  I'm pretty sure it will still have a reference living in `sys.modules` (at least)

Comment: @mgilson Would a `del this_mod` at the end of the loop fix that?

Comment: @Hyperboreus -- you mean `del this_mod`?  No.  That wouldn't fix it.  `del` only removes the reference in the current namespace.  Really though, the best solution is to fix the modules which are building large structures in the global namespace.  There's a reason people always say you shouldn't use global variables :)

Comment: I agree.  At the present moment I don't have control over those modules, but eventually that'll be the solution

Comment: So, I copied vars() to mvars.  Is the memory still referenced by vars()?

Comment: When the for loop terminates, var and mvars will still reference the last objects you processed. You should `del` them.